# "mount error(112): Host is down" on stretch, but not jessie! Why?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, raspbian-stretch, mount

First, some background: the CIFS drive I am trying to mount: `PASSPORT2TB` is connected via USB to a small wifi AP running [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/), and it is shared via the Samba server on that (OpenWRT) host. I want to connect to `PASSPORT2TB` from my two RPi boxes; one runs `jessie`, the other runs `stretch`. I do not have an entry in `/etc/fstab` for `PASSPORT2TB` on either of the RPis. `RPi:stretch` is a new install on a new 3B+; `RPi:jessie` was recently upgraded from wheezy, and has an operational mount point that has worked for... years.

Here's the exchange when I attempt to mount `PASSPORT2TB` from `RPi:stretch`:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.250/PASSPORT2TB ~/mntPassport
Password for root@//192.168.1.250/PASSPORT2TB:  ********
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I've searched for an answer, and tried the `-o` option as follows with no success (you may have to scroll horizontally to see the entire line):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.250/PASSPORT2B mntPassport -o guest,vers=1.0
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
-------------------------------------
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.250/PASSPORT2B mntPassport -o guest,vers=2.0
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Anyone know what is causing this - or how to correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to overcome this issue:

```
sudo mount //192.168.1.250/PASSPORT2TB ~/mntPassport -o username=guest,password=,vers=1.0
```

That said, be aware that there appear to be some "issues" and new twists in the code in Raspbian "Stretch":

1. Whereas Jessie & earlier were happy with `username` or `user`, Stretch **insists** upon `username`
2. The man page for `mount.cifs` states for the version option:

   ```
   vers=SMB protocol version. Allowed values are:

      ·   1.0 - The classic CIFS/SMBv1 protocol. This is the default.
   ```

But this is NOT the default, and therefore the man page is INCORRECT as `vers=1.0` MUST be specified for this to work in Stretch. (see above)

3. Using `vers=2.0` or `vers=3.0` will both fail on Stretch
4. And finally, the error message provided by Stretch is useless:

   `mount error(112): Host is down`

Answer (score -1):

I just went through the same issue.  My solution was to add ",vers=1.0" to the -o list of options.  I know I am not supposed to say thanks in Stackexchange, but I found the solution in another post on SE- Debian.

This worked in fstab Jessie, but not Stretch:
//nst-600nu/PUBLIC /mnt/nst-600 cifs username=guest,password=guest,workgroup=MSHOME,users,auto,_netdev,user_xattr  0  0

This works in Stretch:
//nst-600nu/PUBLIC /mnt/nst-600 cifs username=guest,password=guest,workgroup=MSHOME,users,auto,_netdev,user_xattr,vers=1.0  0  0