# mount samba drives as a guest

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I'm trying to mount a windows network drive as a guest. (on an rPi3+)

```
$ sudo mount -v -t cifs //WinMachine/tv /home/pi/SHARED/TV -o guest
```

and the response:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=fd83:d2df:a9f3::662,unc=\\WinMachine\tv,user=,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Is it somehow still passing a password? What's the problem with this code?

It connects properly on android (without login).

Edit:
I'm able to ping it from the raspberry. It is able to mount the drive if i pass my Windows username/password in the options field.
The drive is shared as RW.
I already `turned off the password protected sharing` in the `Advanced sharing settings`

Comment: This might be more of a Linux question, and not so much a Raspberry Pi-specific question, so I recommend that you look at the suggestions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/mount-error-13-permission-denied. 

If you find something that fixes the problem, you can post an answer to your own question here :) If not, edit your question and add more details about the information you've gathered and the solutions you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the drive can only be mounted this way:

`sudo mount -v -t cifs -o user=,pass=, //WinMachine/tv /home/pi/SHARED/TV`

Comment: I've never seen it done this way, but I've found `mount` to be, *uh - flexible* :)

Answer (score 1):

[There have been instances](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82401/mount-error112-host-is-down-on-stretch-but-not-jessie-why) where RPi's `mount.cifs` seems to behave oddly. Try adding `vers=1.0` after `guest`; i.e.

```
sudo mount -v -t cifs //WinMachine/tv /home/pi/SHARED/TV -o guest,vers=1.0
```

You may also wish to peruse `man mount.cifs`; esp the section `vers=arg`.

Let us know how that works.

Comment: I have tried this and failed in a weird way:
`mount error(2): No such file or directory`
`Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`
i'm pretty sure the paths are correct!

Comment: @MilánPataki: Pretty sure? :) What path are you using from your android device? Can you get an IP address for //WinMachine?? Can you ping it? Also, you've not declared whether your mount is to be `ro` or `rw`... maybe try `-o guest,ro,vers=1.0`. Note that `guest` instead of `username=...` requires your Samba server be configured to allow this.

Comment: Thank you for help and your good questions. yes, I'm sure about the paths :)
I connected to the network drive with TotalCommander for Android, server name: `WinMachine/tv`.  I'm able to ping it. The drive is WR. I will add these info the the issue descripiton.

Comment: I'm found a solution to force an empty login, just posted it here. btw do you have a link how to configure a samba server on windows? It might be useful for me. :)

Comment: @MilánPataki: I put some stuff up on my github site that might be helpful. It's actually spread across 3 different "recipes": [mounting external drives](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/ExternalDrives.md), [sharing drives w/ Samba](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FileShare.md) and [create a music library file server](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/CreatingRationalMusicLibrary.md). Please note this was created for my benefit, and it might not be what you need.